# How can i invoke the Webkit Inspector via Javascript

Tags: webkit

I don't want to use the "Inspect Element" menu item to show the Webkit Inspector. 
How can i invoke him via Javascript?

Comment: You need to clarify.  Do you want to disable the inspect element item? That question is unrelated to how you would invoke the inspector from a script, If that it is your goal you should open a separate question.  Also, I wish nothing but failure on anyone attempting to disable the inspector.

Comment: Huh? What are you asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Even though Web Inspector is tightly integrated into the codebase of the WebKit project, the engine does not expose any way to invoke it from the JavaScript context (nor it should). This kind of thing would only be possible with a vendor-specific JS API exposing this functionality, but it isn't the case. The Web Inspector is a client-side thing, so I don't think it would make any sense, especially that it'd encourage web developers to write code specific only to browsers shipping WebKit and Web Inspector.

Comment: But i'm writing an IDE for Javascript and have my own webkit based browser. So how can i interact with webkit programmatically. Invoking the inspector was just the first of all questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to be more precise. "My own webkit based browser" isn't telling me much. Depending on which WebKit port it's based on (or maybe you've created yet another one?), the answer is different. That said, pretty much every port should have a Web Inspector API that you can use.